# Partial Fractions Integration Help

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

[image: (click here for image of integral)]

So this is the integral and i have tried going through it many times and i can't seem to figure out where i went wrong. The answer in the box is the final answer i came up with. I've used up all my submission attempts for this problem but i would still like to know where i've gone wrong.

[image: my work for the most recent attempt]

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You're going to need to show _what_ you've been doing in order for someone to tell you where you might have gone wrong...

Comment: Yep, sorry about that. I've added it into the main post now

Comment: From the looks of things it seems you have written $-3A=18$ where it should be $3A=18$ so it may be that letting $A=6$ will solve your dilemma with WebAssign.

Comment: Of course, the dreaded sign error. always gets me. Thanks for the help. Feel dumb posting now but i honestly would have never noticed that. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey, don't make your username "the-worst-at-math." I promise you, you're not as bad as you think.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unlikely to be of value to future users and the problem has been resolved in the comments.